# FactoryMuff skips laravel model callbacks

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

When I write tests for a model, I put fake model creating inside the `setUp` method using FactoryMuff.

```
$this->user = FactoryMuff::create('User', array('password' => '12345678'));
```

Inside a model there is a `saving` callback that hashes the password. Callback is triggered (password becomes hashed) until the second test is reached (where password is not hashed). I even checked it with simple var_dump.

```
public function testFirst() { // $this->user is a good model } 
public function testSecond() { // $this->user is a bad model }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer, I just had to call `User::boot()` manually in `setUp` to register callbacks